# Anti-virus on Ubuntu?

Tags: security, antivirus

Hello do I really need anti-virus/anti-maleware protection on my Ubuntu machine?
I only use rkhunter and chkrootkit for rootkit checks but I want to be sure if I need more protection.
Thanks!

Comment: Please use the search. This topic has been beaten to death, resurrected, and beaten to death again. Over and over again. Answer: no, unless you want to scan for virusses before sending a file over to a windows system in your network. Even rkhunter and chrootkit are useless: 99.999999999999% of what they consider an infected file is bogus.

Comment: Official stance: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-antivirus.html Dupe: https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed and https://askubuntu.com/questions/801514/what-antivirus-program-can-i-use-on-ubuntu