# Does Ubuntu 18.04LTS require antivirus/malware?

Tags: security, 18.04, malware, antivirus

(not duplicated because i'm specifying version of Ubuntu, other questions are about ubuntu without version)

Does ubuntu 18.04LTS require antivirus/malware?

wich is the best option? if yes.

i have Nod32 but i'm not sure if this is the best option, useful or at least required.

Lastest Nod32 (Linux) version is 4, looks like Nod32 does not care Linux.

is there a good, professional option?

Comment: IMHO this **is** a duplicate as specifying the version you are using doesn't mean the question is version specific. It's not. Consider the question "How do I get a listing of a directory from the terminal on Ubuntu 18.04. Would the answers be any different?

Comment: No it does not. Common sense is far more important. VSs use windows based rules to scan so useless. And we do not download random softeware; we use a known secure software store that is checked for malware and only download from trusted sources.

Comment: There is only 1 use-case for a VS in linux: if you use linux as a gateway into a windows network you can scan the in and outgoing windows files. That works pretty good. But for a non-windows system... nah.

Comment: I agree with @ElderGeek, but I don't think that every User is at the same level of understanding, and in this case, they just wanted to make sure because they use AskUbuntu as a primary source of information, being new to the community, and having a valid, serious concern about being safe.  Also, since this User obviously doesn't have your level of understanding, it's best to give good advice that can be built off of.

Comment: In my experience, to protect Ubuntu, not useful, not required. If you are running a mail server that may be delivering mail to Windows clients, it's a good idea to use clamav to scan mail attachments prior to delivery, but that has more to do with the end users lack of common sense and Windows security holes than it has to do with Ubuntu. Having said that, I always recommend that my clients that run Windows run AV software. Those that don't heed my advice typically end up paying me more to disinfect their systems than they would have paid for a year or more of AV coverage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Need is a strong word.

If you have your computer in your basement, not connected to the Internet, that you use as a glorified typewriter, then maybe you don't *need* Anti-Virus, because nothing is downloaded.

Maybe you like to download things from the Internet, and try new software.  In this case, you'd be safest running Anti-Virus.

If you are running a service where you accept files from others, then you most certainly need to run Anti-Virus, even if the viruses don't affect your system, as to prevent yourself from propagating the virus and being irresponsible.

Without further details, it will be hard for anybody to give you an accurate answer.  Your use-case and practices will impact the advice given.

[clamav](https://www.clamav.net/) is often used on Linux systems to scan files for malicious content, for various purposes.  Unless you're trying to use some ancient hardware, anything should be capable of running good Anti-Virus with minimum impact.

#### Note

Anti-Virus options haven't changed much with Ubuntu 18.04.   [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801514/what-antivirus-program-can-i-use-on-ubuntu) (and its duplicates) are still good sources of information.

Anybody telling you that you don't need Anti-Virus is probably giving bad advice, or has a lot of knowledge about Linux systems.  Again, your practices, and knowledge, play a big part in your needs.

Comment: i'm a developer, i always use Internet, i really don't have "good" information useful for hackers/spywares/virus, but who likes to be exposed?, i'm gonna try clamav, so my conclusion is "yes ubuntu need antivirus/etc, but depending on use case". Thanks bro.